# Merge rows by one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column `name` and `value` and I need to write a `select` to merge all rows with the same `name` into one row (something like `distinct`) except when I use `distinct` then I can't merge/sum `value` column.

Example:

```
name value
A     10
B     5
C     20
A     5
C     1
B     5
```

And the result would be:

```
A     15
B     10
C     21
```

This is my select so far, but it is not "merged", it does exactly what my example shows.

```
select
    projects.name, 
    sum(current_date - (projects_programmers.joined_at))
    from projects, projects_programmers
where projects.id = projects_programmers.project_id
group by projects.name, projects_programmers.joined_at
```

Comment: `select name, sum(value) from the_table group by name`

Comment: Why vote down? Is there something unclear or bad formatted?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh, thanks man, I totaly  forgot about using just `group by name`. I have removed `group by joined_at` and it works perfect. Thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you write it as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name, sum(value) value from yourTableName group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct
 "name", sum("value") over (partition by "name")
from table_name
```

you can use window function for this

Comment: That's a pretty complicated way of writing `select name, sum(value) from table_name group by name`

Comment: yes :) I was lookign at OPs `sum(current_date - (projects_programmers.joined_at))` while writing. And doubts on efficiency of that to get int in `"value"` took all my attention, so I just gave any working solution while thinking on the other OPs topic